# How do I append to a list once in a double-for loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to append a number to a list only when `i > 5` and an empty string when it has no number greater than 5.

My problem is trying to append for the number of times equal to a single empty string and according to the first for loop `for i in range(0,10)`

This is what I've tried:

```
my_list = []

for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range (0,5):
        if i > 5:
            my_list.append(i)
        else:
            my_list.append('')
```

But I am getting the empty strings looping over both for-loops and I'm a bit confused on how to proceed.

The output should be a list with a total of 10 elements as:

`output = ['', '', '', '', '', '', 6, 7, 8, 9]`

> Second example as the one above may have over-simplified things:

`file_names_short = ['apple pie', 'apple cake', 'carrot apple', 'carrot cake']`

```
threshold = 0.70
result_list = []
for x in file_names_short:
    for y in company_list:
        if similar(x, y) > threshold:
            result = x
            result_list.append(result)
        else:
            result_list.append('')
```

Which explains why it is necessary to have the second loop.

Comment: Your code will produce 50 results, not 10.  10 x 5 --> each of the 10 iterations of i will each produce 5 iterations of j (and you do nothing with j's value).

Comment: So `result_list = output` after your loop runs @RohanB ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh output = result_list, yes.

Comment: What does `file_names_short` look like? and `company_list` looks like, can you specify that too ? Also your new code copied as is has a syntax error! Please check your indents!

Comment: `file_names_short = ['apple pie', 'apple cake', 'carrot apple', 'carrot cake']

Comment: You still need to show where you define `result`.  when it is first encountered in line 4, it will be `None`.

Comment: Also update all those names in the question instead of comments for all answerers to see!

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should simply get rid of the loop i and j example, since it really does not accurately depict your question.

Comment: Also what does `similar(x,y)` function looks like! You need to define all the variables in question before you expect answers! We cannot do the guess work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to get "Result should have `''` for each `file_name` that does not match condition, and `file_name` if it matches condition":

```py
Source = ['apple pie', 'apple cake', 'carrot apple', 'carrot cake']
#            |             |            |                   |
#           bad          Good          Bad                 Good
#            |             |            |                   |
Result = [   ''      , 'apple cacke',   ''          ,  'carrot cake']
```

Is that what you want?

```py
my_list = []

for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range (0,5):
        if i > 5:
            my_list.append(i)
            break
    else:  # else of the `for`!!! not of the `if`
        # Condition did not match, so cycle was not broken - append ''
        my_list.append('')
```

```py
threshold = 0.70
result_list = []

for x in file_names_short:
    for y in company_list:
        if similar(x, y) > threshold:
            result_list.append(x)
            break
    else:
        result_list.append('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have an extra inner for loop, when your outer loop does the job for you

```
my_list = []

for i in range(0,10):
    if i > 5:
        my_list.append(i)
    else:
        my_list.append('')
print(my_list)
```

The output is

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

When you had your extra inner loop, every operation of `my_list.append` was being done 5 times for each `i`, hence you see a total of 35 spaces, and 5 numbers each! Which is

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: The extra loop has other operations in it which I did not specify as they're irrelevant to the question. It's necessary for my purpose to have the second loop also.

Comment: But in your question, you say `output = ['', '', '', '', '', '', 6, 7, 8, 9]`, which is what we get now! Can you clarify that @RohanB ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to loop, for numbers 0 to 9 inclusive, and for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 you want to insert a blank string, and for 6, 7, 8 and 9, you want to insert those numbers.

This does not require a double loop, I'm unsure where you got the inner/secondary loop idea from but its completely unneeded and is the exact reason you're getting more than what you asked for.

```
my_list = []

for i in range(0,10):
    if i > 5:
        my_list.append(i)
    else:
        my_list.append('')

print(my_list)
```

outputs:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: User has since clarified their question required a double loop for other reasons so this is not useful

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it:

```
my_list = [i if i > 5 else '' for i in range(10)]
```

It outputs:

```
[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Wish you the best.